# How can I give read-only perms to a file-structure and allow write on certain folders?

Tags: windows, file-permissions, icacls

So I am trying to use *icacls* to only let a user add and access documents inside folders with specific keywords.

I cannot get exactly what I want however. Anyone have any tips? I am unfamiliar with Windows' permissions. Thanks!

Here is the code I have come up with so far:

(The account I am modifying the permissions of is called *test*)

```
echo >pdfFolderList.txt
:: Remove any permissions
icacls %~dp0* /remove test /T

:: Deny all access to everything
icacls %~dp0* /deny test:f /T

:: grant read access to everything
icacls %~dp0* /grant test:r /T

:: grant write access to folders with keywords
FOR /d /r %%a in ("*PDF Current Docs*", "*Shipping", "*QA Docs", "*Photos", "*Misc") DO (
    echo %%a>>pdfFolderList.txt
    icacls "%%a" /grant:r test:f /T
    )
```

An example file-structure would be:

```
├───Server_Files_Example_Folder
│   ├───A_JOB_NUMBER - Native Current Docs
│   ├───A_JOB_NUMBER - PDF Current Docs
│   │   ├───Drawings
│   ├───A_JOB_NUMBER - TEI Quotes Customer POs and Change Orders
│   ├───Correspondence
│   │   ├───From Customer
│   │   └───To Customer
│   ├───Docs From Customer
│   │   ├───Approval Drawings
│   ├───Misc
│   ├───Photos
│   ├───Programs etc
│   │   ├───As Shipped
│   │   └───Field Changes
│   ├───QA Docs
│   │   └───Markups
│   ├───Service
│   │   ├───Correspondence
│   │   └───Reports
│   ├───Shipping
│   │   └───test
│   └───Vendor Docs
│       ├───Order Confirmation
│       ├───POs
│       └───Vendor Quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

I recomend not to use deny on the NTFS file system ACL's becaus it is messing up the inheritance of the permission of the folders above. If you do have a graphical interface on a Windows machine it is very easy to do this manually in the *security* tab of your folder under *extended*

Comment: But I wouldn't be able to set permissions on certain folders based on keywords would I? Because I have a large file structure, and I only want this account being able to modify files that are in a folder with a certain keyword (e.g. Shipping)

Comment: The "deny" access is definitely wrong in this case.  Ignoring the keyword folders for the moment, it doesn't make sense to deny full access and then grant read access; the deny rule takes precedence, so the grant rule does exactly nothing.  Unless the test account is getting access from somewhere else (the parent folder, or a group membership) you don't need the deny rule anyway.  Deny is the default.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ok thanks, that makes sense. So all I need to do is first grant read access on everything, then do the for loop to grant read/write for the specific folders with keywords?

Comment: Yes.  But also, you should probably be using inheritance rather than `*` and `/T` and RX rather than R.  Something like `icacls %~dp0 /grant test:(OI)(CI)(RX)` and `icacls "%%a" /grant test:(OI)(CI)F`

Comment: @HarryJohnston I tried that, but the test user can now add or remove files from any folder for some reason. Is this because of inherited permissions?

Comment: To clarify, in your example diagram above, do you want the user to be able to write files to both "Shipping" and "Shipping\test" or *just* "Shipping"?  If the latter, you only want (OI) and not (CI).

Comment: @HarryJohnston I would want them to have access to Shipping and Shipping/test.

Comment: You've probably got the wrong permissions at the top of the tree then.  Perhaps via a group that test is a member of.  The `whoami /groups` command (when logged in as the test user) will show you the list of tokens the user holds, look for them in the list of permissions.